Possible MathJax upgrade
Since not all interested MO users frequent meta.SE, here’s a heads up that some work is underway towards the possibility of upgrading MathJax v2 to v3 or v4 on Stack Exchange sites including MathOverflow. It is still in experimental stage, but any registered user can test it themselves by turning MathJax v3 on in profile preferences (https://mathoverflow.net/users/preferences/).
See Upgrade plans for MathJax v3/v4 for the full announcement with many more details.

Finally!  A not-insignificant chunk of my MMO activity is reporting MathJax bugs to which the answer is "they're fixed, but SE is stuck on MathJax v2."  Thanks for sharing the good news, and the mechanism to opt in!

For anyone who doesn't click across to your linked MSE post, two very important points:

Extension TeX/begingroup is not yet implemented (but may be in a future release)



Note: Grouping allowed expressions from one post to not impact another by sideloading resources. This is not implemented for v3 so it's possible to have side-effects from multiple different posts on the same page. This may be a blocker for GA.


…

…

Packages that are \require'd in many have been moved around, notably AMScd which seems to break spectacularly enough that JS throws for the entire page. I'll try to get a quick turnaround to patch that up, so we can focus on more edge case error reporting here.


Thanks for x-posting Emil!

What are the differences in the way MathJax is used and in its abilities?

I was sort of hoping that maybe upgrading to MathJax 3 would fix this bug, but alas, it doesn't seem to help.

Are there some changes under way even for default MathJax?  Because the AMScd breakage is too much for me, I wound up not switching on the experimenal v3, and I have not changed my HTML renderer, but occasionally it looks like the math font has changed. \ @MichaelHardy, re, there is a What's new for v3, although it seems mostly to be internals-focussed. The MSE post linked above says some more about how it might impact us.
